# Vim : replacing entire word based on partial match search on all lines

Tags: regex, vim, vi

I want to replace all occurrences of a word in a file with a partial match. 
For example, search using "75008" and replace entire word with "12345678901"

Actual content

```
75003681846 75008494799 75213014616 
75003681846 75008494795 75213014613                                       
75003681846 75008513200 75213014614                                                   
75003681846 75008494798 75213014617
```

Expected content after replace

```
75003681846 12345678901 75213014616 
75003681846 12345678901 75213014613                                       
75003681846 12345678901 75213014614                                                   
75003681846 12345678901 75213014617
```

How to do it in vim

Thanks
Red Ant

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\< and \> match word boundaries.

\S* matches all non-whitespace.

s does substitution.

% applies it to the entire file.

```
:%s/\<\S*75008\S*\>/12345678901/g
```

Answer (score 0):

For your example also works:

`:%s/75008\d\+/12345678901`

`\d` match simple digit, and `\+` matches 1 or more of the preceding characters, according to https://vimregex.com/